# Axios.post returning :ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after API call

Tags: reactjs, axios

I've made a axios `post` request in my react component, which makes a request to `twilio` to send a text message to my phone from a route on my server.

The text message and payload are transmitted successfully however when opening the network tab in the console I get this error in a minute or two.

`POST http://localhost:8080/api/twilio net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Any notion out there how to solve this?

[image]

This is the code from my react component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Grid, Segment, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import './test.css';

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { phonenumber: '' };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ phonenumber: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    return axios
      .post('/api/twilio', {
        phonenumber: this.state.phonenumber,
      })
      .then(resp => resp.data)
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    const { phonenumber } = this.state;
    console.log('phonenumber', phonenumber);

    return (
      <Grid columns={1} stackable textAlign="center">
        <Grid.Column width={1} />
        <Grid.Column width={14}>
          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Segment stacked>
              <Form.Group id="form-group" inline>
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <Form.Input onChange={this.handleChange} value={phonenumber} placeholder="+12223334444" />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Button id="form-group-button" content="Submit" />
            </Segment>
          </Form>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={1} />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

**Update:**

This is the twilio route on the backend.

```
const router = require('express').Router();

module.exports = router;

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let SID = 'ACc5b16ad0cefc3b514e69bc30636726e2';
  let TOKEN = '3145fb41afe308f22b0b7c647e6a8e17';
  let SENDER = '+18622256079';

  if (!SID || !TOKEN) {
    return res.json({ message: 'add TWILIO_SID and TWILIO_TOKEN to .env file.' });
  }

  let client = require('twilio')(SID, TOKEN);

  client.messages
    .create({
      to: req.body.phonenumber,
      from: SENDER,
      body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?',
    })
    .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
});
```

Comment: Could you include the server-side code for the `/api/twilio` route?

Comment: @FabianSchultz Sure, I updated it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your route on the server, nothing will ever be returned to the client because `SID` and `TOKEN` are always defined (at least in your example). To make sure that the request will not fail, you will need to send at least some response back after the Twilio request, e.g.:

```babel
client.messages
  .create({
    to: req.body.phonenumber,
    from: SENDER,
    body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?'
  })
  .then(message => {
    console.log(message.sid);

    // Either just send an empty, successful response or some data (e.g. the `sid`)
    res.status(200).send(message.sid);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);

    // In case of an error, let the client know as well.
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
```

Comment: Ahh, I didn't even think of that or realize I was doing that. Think I got carried away with getting the text message to work; Thank you so much for your answer!